# Jquery Ajax Send multiple checkbox values to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to serialize rather to push the elements value but still I get the array with no value. please anyone to help me figure out my problem
this is what I am trying to

```
<input type="checkbox" class="benf" name="benf[]" value="Angelus">

var arr=[];
        $('input[name*="benf"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                arr.push($(this).attr('value'))
            }
        });
        var p = $('input .benf').serializeArray();
        console.log(p);
        console.log(arr);
        $.ajax({
            url:'myphp.php',
            type:'post',
            dataType:'text',
            data:{mylist:arr},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(xx){
                console.log(xx);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are the checkboxes checked? If not, checkboxes doesn't have a value unless they are checked. Also, `$('input .benf')` should be `$('input.benf')`. All you need to do to send all checked checkboxes is: `data: $('input.benf').serialize(),`

Comment: I have tried to validate checkboxes with this if(($('input[name*="benf"]:checked').length)<=0){} and it works but the rest even the one you tried to give to me it still gives mes the same result

Comment: Thank Magnus, I figure out my problem, your code is perfect, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 var arr=[];

    $("input:checkbox[name*=benf]:checked").each(function(){
         arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    var p = $('input.benf').serializeArray();
    console.log(p);
    console.log(arr);
    $.ajax({
        url:'myphp.php',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'text',
        data:{mylist:arr},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(xx){
            console.log(xx);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When writing an answer, you should include an explanation of what you have changed and why.

Comment: Yeah real sorry guys!! It is just I had a code line looks like this $('.div').css('display','none') before this $("input:checkbox[name*=benf]:checked").each(function(){
         arr.push($(this).val());
    }); Actually that line hides the DIV layer containing the checkboxes

Comment: But you Answers a all perfect I have tried them they work nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[];
         $.each($("input[name='approve_blog']:checked"), function(){            
                arr.push($(this).val());
        });

        console.log(arr);
        $.ajax({
            url:'myphp.php',
            type:'post',

            data:{'mylist' : arr },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(xx){
                console.log(xx);
            }
        });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="blog_checkbox" name="approve_blog"   value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" class="blog_checkbox" name="approve_blog"   value="2"  />
```

Comment: You should explain in brief that what you did special.